# why doesnt the AccessDeniedHandler works with request dispatcher?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            logger.debug("   ++++++++++++++++++++++++ handler handling handling things :D        +++++++++++++++++++++ ");
             String love = (String) request.getAttribute("love");
         RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error/403");
            logger.debug("   ++++++++++++++++++++++++ doing request forward     +++++++++++++++++++++ "+request.getAttribute("pain"));

            requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
            request.setAttribute("love","love");

    //        response.sendRedirect(accessDeniedUrl);
    //
    //       request.getSession().setAttribute("message","You do not have permission to access this page!");


        }
```

That is my handle method after implementing AccessDeniedHandler of spring security, it works well with sendRedirect but as I need request in another place I have to use request dispatcher, but it doesnt work and gives 404. I have put all the logging levels on debug and even trace but no error is being printed except going to 404 page. Any ideas?

Comment: Then your `handle` method is never getting hit. Check (post) your configuration.

Comment: It is getting a hit, I could see both the log messages. I have added this to <http> config of spring security.

Comment: Do you have a resource (servlet, jsp, wtv) mapped to `/error/403`? This is an actual resource it's looking for, not a new request.

Comment: Well, actually, it is being used by spring container, do I need to define anything in web.xml?

Comment: I'm confused. What is `"/error/403"`? Is that a url you want to make an http request to?

Comment: yes, that is the url.

Comment: Explain what you mean by _but as I need request in another place_. I would've used `sendRedirect` like you said.

Comment: Yes, but I have few request attributes which I want to access in a view associated with that url, and I am not getting it using sendRedirect as it empties it.